# How to add zero values in beginning and end of Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
    Inbound Value
1   Nan
2   Nan
3   Nan
4   ...
5   ...
19  Nan
20  130
21  130
22  140
23  140
24  170
25  170
25  170
26  ...
27  210
28  Nan
29  Nan
30  ...
..  ...
131 Nan
```

I would like to drop most of values which are `Nan` but keeping only 11 first values and keep also the last 11 `Nan`.

I know that `data = data.dropna()` drop all `Nan` values but I want to have as I described.

Comment: Where is your coding attempt?  What is wrong with it?

Comment: The title doesn't match your question

Comment: Can you add a decent dataset? Your data goes from 5 to 19 from 30 to 131 and what are those `...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use numpy's [`r_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to set range of indexes to a value and then drop remaining `NaN`

```
df.iloc[pd.np.r_[0:10, -11:0], df.columns.get_loc('Inbound Value')] = 0
data.dropna()
```